# What is a typical defense mechanism/setup against flooding back-end sql calls?

Tags: html, sql-server

I'm interested in figuring out what is a typical scenario of preventing the following attack scenario:

Back-end has as SQL server. Front end a simple "Hello World" HTML that passes an input (say user name) to be stored in SQL (sanitized). How does one typically prevent an attacker from writing a for loop and hammering the SQL with millions of store request until resources are exhausted? Like putting a cap on requests/second per IP?

P.S. Please part my ignorance - a desktop software developer trying to expand my borders :)
Thanks!

Comment: CAPTCHA or Proof of Work (make client calculate prime factors of large number). IP rate limiting won't work against someone using an anonymizing proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database part of this is largely irrelevant, as a non-insignificant portion of your load will be on your web server rather than the database.

There are four common ways to implement rate limiting:

1. Perform rate checks against the user context, client IP, and other information within the application. This will allow more granular control of what types of requests you want to limit, and from who, but has the downside that the request must've already hit the web server and application in order for the checks to be performed.
2. Perform rate limiting on a host-based firewall, such as [iptables](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/187/Using_iptables_to_rate-limit_incoming_connections). This allows you to reduce the load on your web application server daemon and any backend resources, but doesn't (trivially) allow you to make rules around which requests should be limited in different ways, as it operates at the transport layer (TCP/IP) rather than at the application layer (HTTP).
3. Install an appliance in front of the web server which performs deep packet inspection (DPI), or acts as a web application firewall (WAF). These are often called Layer 7 Firewalls or "full stack" firewalls, as they are designed to operate on application layer content (e.g. HTTP/HTTPS) as well as lower layers. You could argue that they fall under the umbrella term of Intrusion Prevention Systems (IPS), at least in terms of inline configuration. These can be very useful for terminating unwanted content before it even hits the target server, and can be very powerful, but have the downside that you usually have to put a lot of configuration work in, or buy an applicance.
4. Use a "security as a service" (SaaS) product in front of your server, which is designed to mitigate attacks such as flooding and DDoS. An example of this is [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/). These aren't usually directly designed to prevent the exact types of attack you mentioned, but are pretty good at blackholing malicious automated traffic and DoS attacks.

These methods are not mutually exclusive; in fact, a combined approach is often the most effective.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rate limiting`, that's a module for that on [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ratelimit.html), [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html), and [IIS](https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions).

Rate limiting can hurt people standing behind a proxy (like me), so you should not deny access based on the limit, but to employ another defense as soon as the limit is reached. A captcha based defense is useful, and some captcha systems (like [ReCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)) can be processed without exausting your resources.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, Usually user/ip based rate limiting is used to prevent excessive requests. If your application detects a user/ip submitting requests beyond a threshold your application should stop storing the requests in the database to prevent a denial-of-service from occurring.

Comment: I see, but i guess my question being, if I use a "popular" webhost provider, is this something that is set automatically, or do I have to implement this myself?

Comment: You'll probably need to implement it yourself. I haven't seen any providers specifically listing throttling abusive user requests as a feature. CloudFlare does offer DDoS protection as a premium feature for Business and Enterprise users though.